# ng-repeat not rendering array changes in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of items being displayed on a page using ng-repeat. Below is the html.

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="container" >
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Found {{searchResults.length}} results that match your search <br /><small>Click on any result to view details</small></h3>
    </div>
    ----
    <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="item in searchResults track by $index">
        <a ng-href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.test_name}}</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text" ng-bind-html="item.synonyms"></p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This array is created when the application loads. Below is the function in the controller where the array is modified.

When the user types something in the search box and hits search, I want the location to change as shown in the code and a list of results displayed using the ngrepeat directive.

```
$scope.onClickSearch = function () {
    console.log("Search Click in Controller - " + $scope.searchString);
    $scope.searchResults = new Array();

    /*
        remove special characters and html tags from the synonyms and check if the name 
        or synonym contains the search string.
    */
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            var synonyms = $scope.items[i].synonyms
            var testName = $scope.items[i].test_name.toLowerCase();
            if ((testName.indexOf($scope.searchString) > -1) || (synonyms.indexOf($scope.searchString) > -1)) {
                var searchItem = $scope.items[i];
                $scope.searchResults.push(searchItem);
            }
        };
        $location.url("/search");
    });
    console.log($scope.searchResults); //Array is shown to be updated here.
```

When the function updates the array, the html displayed on the page does not change. [image: That is what I see.] The log in the console shows the right thing. I tried `$scope.$digest()` and `$scope.$apply()` There is no change in the result.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co:443/t0CjyI8RG5d5tm2qGXDp) with the recreated issue. This should give a more detailed description of the issue. When I type in something to search and hit the search button, The view does not show the search results.

I have a second question open which is similar to this one but it went unanswered. This is my second attempt with a slightly different explanation.

Comment: Have you tried declaring $scope.searchResults outside of the method, see if it changes then?

Comment: that gives me a few things to think about. I get an empty array outside the method

Comment: Can you log the results of $scope.items in that controller? Does it have contents?

Comment: yes it does have contents. please feel free to edit the plunk

Comment: @rrd when I declare it outside the function, and log it outside the function, I get the log twice and both times it is empty.

Comment: I think the onClickSearch function in the controller does not see the same scope variables. How can I change that?

Comment: Altered it a little, but it works, https://plnkr.co/edit/kWqje5Xn17259ixaqbf5 I used the factory to store the search results then restored then on the reload.

Comment: @rrd When you search for "5" and click search, it works, when you then change it to "5a" and click on search, it does not update the list. I again tried `$scope.$apply()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

By calling $location.url("/search"); you are instantialing the controller again so you will have an empty $scope.searchResults
use $rootScope to keep your data even after re-instantiating the controller

```
    catalogEditor.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$http', 'DataFactory', '$location', '$timeout', '$rootScope'
    , function ($scope, $http, DataFactory, $location, $timeout, $rootScope) {

...
    $scope.onClickSearch = function () {
    console.log("Search Click in Controller - " + $scope.searchString);
    $rootScope.searchResults = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            var synonyms = $scope.items[i].synonyms
            var testName = $scope.items[i].test_name.toLowerCase();
            if ((testName.indexOf($scope.searchString) > -1) || (synonyms.indexOf($scope.searchString) > -1)) {
                var searchItem = $scope.items[i];
                $rootScope.searchResults.push(searchItem);
            }
        };
        $location.url("/search");
    });
    console.log($rootScope.searchResults);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
catalogEditor.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$http', 'DataFactory', '$location', '$timeout', '$route', '$routeParams'
                                        , function ($scope, $http, DataFactory, $location, $timeout, $route, $routeParams) {

$scope.items = DataFactory.getSearchScope();
$scope.selectedCatalogCd = '';
$scope.searchString = '';
// Get our stored data, or, a blank array;
$scope.searchResults = DataFactory.get() || [];

function init() {
    $route.reload(); // had to force a reload for the changes to be displayed
}

$scope.onItemSelected = function () {
    console.log("In Controller - " + $scope.selectedCatalogCd);
    $location.path("/details/" + $scope.selectedCatalogCd + ".json");
};

$scope.onClickSearch = function () {
    console.log("Search Click in Controller - " + $scope.searchString);
    /*
        remove special characters and html tags from the synonyms and check if the name 
        or synonym contains the search string.
    */
    $scope.searchResults = [];
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        var synonyms = $scope.items[i].synonyms
        if (synonyms !== "") {
            synonyms = synonyms.replace(/(<(\s*)(br)(\s*)>)/gi, ' ');
            synonyms = synonyms.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').toLowerCase();
        }
        var testName = $scope.items[i].test_name.toLowerCase();
        if ((testName.indexOf($scope.searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1) || (synonyms.indexOf($scope.searchString) > -1)) {
            var searchItem = $scope.items[i];
            $scope.searchResults.push(searchItem);
        }
    }
    // Store the data;
    console.log("New Size of Search Results - ", $scope.searchResults.length);
    DataFactory.set($scope.searchResults);
    $scope.searchResults = [];
    if ($location.path() !== '/search') {
        $location.path("/search");
        $location.replace();
    } else {
        init();
    }
};
}])
```

It is a bit clumsy but it works. There was no other solution that I could find. The app is not a very high traffic app so it will do just fine.
Here is the updated plunker https://plnkr.co/t0CjyI8RG5d5tm2qGXDp

Thanks,
Paras